# Find device orientation using Accelerometer data x,z,y

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, math, accelerometer

How can we find the device orientation from `x,y,z(accelerometer)`.
I was trying to get the device orientation by identifying the `x,y,z` values but it differs. I'm getting different values for iPhone,iPad. Is there any way to find using Accelerometer because I'm using this for background app. UIDeviceOrientation will not work for background app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should answer your question. http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-accelerometer-device-orientation/

Comment: thanks. i came across that link.but i'm looking to find the `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`. do you have any idea that we can find with atan2()?

Comment: oh. Sorry I havent used this in my apps. Good luck!